# How to create a text file that uses user input from Irvine library to write onto it

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

How do I create a text file that updates values inputted to by the user using Irvine's library?

for example for my data I have:

```
.data

frstValue BYTE "Enter first value", 0dh, 0ah, 0
scndValue BYTE "Enter second value', 0dh, 0ah, 0
seperator BYTE "," , 0
buffer DWORD 500 dup(?)    
filename BYTE "valuesEntered.txt",
fileHandle HANDLE ?
```

for my code, I'd have something along the lines of

```
mov edx, OFFSET frstValue
call WriteString
mov edx, OFFSET buffer
mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer
call ReadString

mov edx, OFFSET scndVal
call WriteString
mov edx, OFFSET buffer
mov ecx, SIZEOF buffer
call ReadString

mov edx, OFFSET filename
call CreateOutputFile
inc eax
mov fileHandle, eax

mov eax, fileHandle             
mov edx, OFFSET buffer
mov ecx, LENGTHOF buffer
call WriteToFile
```

I'm pretty much stuck here.

When I enter my values the edx reg overwrites the second user input with the one that was first written. What I'm trying to do is add the second user input at the end of the first. So it kind of look like this:

input 1: 20
input 2: 30

result: 20,30

instead, I just get 30

Comment: Since you used the same buffer of course it does. Easiest is to 1) create file 2) read 1st string 3) write 1st string to file 4) write comma 5) read 2nd string 6) write 2nd string to file.

Comment: the "edx register" contains just memory address, and the content in the memory gets overwritten, if you ask for user input twice, into the same memory region. Try to read something about computer memory and architecture and how basic data types are stored in computers. Also check in debugger memory view and see yourself, how the content of memory is modified by particular instructions/calls...

Comment: I got the idea of having to create a file and writing on to it. And the looping the process of having to write onto the file. Im just having trouble going about that.

Comment: @Jester ideally what I have done was `call WriteToFile` after the first input then `mov edx, ',' ` reg then `call WriteToFile` then ask for second user input, then `call WriteToFIle` but after doing so im left with an empty file.

Comment: You can't just `mov edx, ','`, you need to store that into memory and pass its address. You should have gotten a crash from that.

Comment: @Jester so id do something like `mov edx, seperator` is what youre saying? I'm really confused right now. :( i cant do `mov edx, seperator` because it has to be the same size.

Comment: Why is when you pass `call WriteToFile` once the only thing save in the text file is the first user input?